# PayPal IPN History Page Bug (Resend Messages Not Working)

Tags: paypal, history, paypal-ipn

I use Zapier to send PayPal IPN messages to Freshbooks to create new clients from a sale.

A few seconds earlier Zapier sends a message from my Wufoo order forms to create a new invoice (I then link them up manually after in Freshbooks).

Wufoo hijacks the Freshbooks API and my Zapier 'Zaps' from PayPal to Freshbooks fail.

I get around this by going to PayPal IPN history once per day and resending the IPN messages making the Zaps successful.

This is not too much trouble for me.

However, for the past 2 weeks or so the resend message on the PayPal IPN history page has not been working. It says successful but does not add the usual '(resent)' items to the history list and nothing is being sent to Zapier.

Is there a known issue with IPN history at the moment? Anything else I can do or just have to wait for PayPal to fix it?

Cheers,

P.

Comment: I have the same issue, as does an associate. On 4/4/2013 both our IPN records started going wrong. In the IPN history, the Notification URL shows as blank, the IPN send date shows as some time in 2984/5 and the IPN message shows as blank. Trying to resend these IPNs gets you a cheery "IPNs resent succesfully" message but they are not actually sent. Or perhaps they are sent to the blank Notification URL. But then if you use the "Resend to profile URL" checkbox which should override that, you still get the same cheery message and no actual resend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known issue as I have had the same problems for the last couple of weeks.  I sent a trouble ticket to Paypal and received the following response: "*Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Services. We are aware of this issue and we are working to resolve it.
I will research this matter further and update you with more information as it becomes available.*"

That was 4/13.  I sent another message today asking for an update, but have not yet received a response.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as of today, I contacted them as well.

Comment: What page is it you submit the tech support tickets to? I got redirected to this forum.

Comment: I got an email the other day about a scheduled site upgrade happening in a few weeks, I hope they're not waiting to roll that out before they fix it :-(

Comment: The page i've always used is http://www.paypal.com/mts.

Once you register, you can submit tickets and view the ticket history.

Comment: Ah right, didn't know about that. Submitted a ticket now. Also complained on the phone the other day.

Comment: Hello Patrick,

We're aware of this issue and our engineers are working to resolve this. Unfortunately there is no alternative workaround at this time.
Please note that this does not affect the IPN message itself; it's solely related to the resend & display of IPN messages.

Thomas

Comment: I can confirm this.  All of my original IPN messages are being sent and received as they should be.  Unfortunately, I know that, in your case, you need the re-send capability.

Comment: Just FYI, I just received an email stating that this issue had been resolved and I can confirm that my IPN history is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

After pestering tech support some more I got this answer:

**"the update for the History is planed for next week."**

Comment: a month to fix this bug, for a company as big as PayPal I think that's a pretty poor show, boooooo!